Is there a way to prove this possible coincidence related to the Riemann Zeta Function?
So, I have been toying around with the Riemann Zeta Function as of late, and one of its properties that I am aware of is that when $s = 1,$ the result diverges. However, I've always thought of setting $s$ as a value extremely close to, but not quite $1$, so I did.
When I did so, I got the following interesting results, as shown by WolframAlpha, rounded to $5$ decimal places.
$\zeta(1.1) = 10.58449\ldots$
$\zeta(1.01) = 100.57794\dots$
$\zeta(1.001) = 1000.57729\ldots$
This is such a strange coincidence to me, that I have an inkling that the floor of $\zeta(1 + 10^{-n})$ is $10^n$ for $n > 0.$ However, because this function is so complicated, I can't really have a proof for it other than just testing out a few values, and I would like to know if such a relation is true or it starts to break down at a certain value of $n.$
Also I apologise for the bad formatting: this is my first time using the website.

$\displaystyle \sum_{n = 1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{n^{1+\varepsilon}} \approx \int_1^{\infty} \frac{1}{x^{1+\varepsilon}} \ \mathrm{d}x = \left[ -\frac{x^{-\varepsilon}}{\varepsilon}\right]_{1}^{\infty} = \frac{1}{\varepsilon}$

This is true. It amounts to the statement that the pole at $s = 1$ has order $1$ and the residue is also $1$. So, equivalently, $\zeta \left( 1 + \frac{1}{z} \right)$ has a Taylor series expansion which begins $z + \dots $.

Well, okay. To get the floor function statement we also need to know that the constant term is positive but less than $1$. This is also true; as you can see from your calculations, it is approximately $0.577 \dots $ and turns out to be the Euler-Mascheroni constant: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%27s_constant
